# Minimisation of html resources

Tags: html, build-process

On a `View page source` of **amazon.in**, I see that HTML page is not minimized.

For performance reasons, html, and other resources are minimized.

Do we have any reasons for not minimizing the resources that are rendered?

Comment: There are thousends of sites, where HTML is not minimized. I bet, it more than 60% of the sites.

Comment: "For performance reasons, html and other resources are minimised." - you just stated that it wasn't. Please clarify your question

Comment: @JoSSte I think the question is why don't they minimized, does they have any reason for it. Pagespeed, and every tool like that is always suggest you to minimize the html/js/css.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Correct. Why do not they minimise? Any reason?

Comment: Why should? They are just big enough and have a tons of relevated content to do not minimize... Optimalization could be a good thing, but don't forget: content is the king